# Date select query selects tomorrows values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [PivotedData15]
  where ReadingDate BETWEEN '2019-02-11 00:01:00' AND  '2019-02-12 00:00:00'
  and Serial='2219'
```

It brings back tomorrows values for the 12th and not values between the 11th and 12th.

I have to have midnight on the following day on the 11th at the end of the readings (at midnight as that is a valid reading for the day).

I want to understand why, this query brings back tomorrows values, which begs the question of what is the point in having `between` or `> <` etc.

Do all dates in a between statement have to be on the same day? 
Is it bringing back tomorrows values because there is a tomorrow value in the data set at the end?

I have added a file in the drop box with the output called Data. I cannot get SQL Fiddle to work.

[Dropbox for code and results](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jaime70dce5vszp/AACHUXqwuk1Rbd92uxnpGXTJa?dl=0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BETWEEN` is inclusive.  Presumably, you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM [PivotedData15]
WHERE ReadingDate >= '2019-02-11' AND
      ReadingDate < '2019-02-12' AND
      Serial = '2219';
```

Based on your description, I am not clear on whether the comparisons are exactly what you need (do yo want `>`/`<=` for instance?).  But individual comparisons with the two end-points is the way to go.

I strongly discourage you from using `BETWEEN` with date/time values.  Aaron Bertrand has a very good blog on the subject [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: Talk about the bleeding obvious. Thank you for that. I will read that immediately!